# Using the Algolia Kotlin Client

Tags: kotlin, algolia

I'm trying to add the algolia kotlin client to my project, but all I'm left with is:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.algolia:algoliasearch-client-kotlin-jvm:1.3.61

According to algolias wiki
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/kotlin/?language=kotlin

All I have to to is add the maven repository (I assume to my project level gradle file?) and import the client (In the app level gradle file, I think)

I tried that but am left with the error message above.

Answer (score 0):

if you use android, you can use:

```
implementation "com.algolia:algoliasearch-client-kotlin-android:1.3.1"
```

> Important: starting from version 1.4.0 the library is compatible only
>   with kotlin version 1.3.70 or higher; for previous versions of kotlin,
>   please use version 1.3.1 of the library.

[ref](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-kotlin#-getting-started)